# Property '$keycloak' does not exist on type 'Vue'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, keycloak

I am getting the following error in my Vue.js router code (see snippet below):

```
Property '$keycloak' does not exist on type 'Vue'
```

The thing is my code compiles and works but when I try console log `router.app` I don't see the attribute `$keycloak`.

I'm beginner in Vue.js.

Thanks for your help.

```
    import VueRouter, { RouteConfig } from "vue-router";
    import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
    import About from "../views/About.vue";

    const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
      {
        path: "/",
        name: "Home",
        component: Home,
        meta: {
          isAuthenticated: false,
        },
      },
      {
        path: "/about",
        name: "About",
        component: About,
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: true,
        },
      },
    ];

    const router = new VueRouter({
      mode: "history",
      base: process.env.BASE_URL,
      routes,
    });

    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      console.log(router.app);
      console.log(router.app.$keycloak);
      if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (router.app.$keycloak.authenticated) {
          next();
        } else {
          const loginUrl = router.app.$keycloak.createLoginUrl();
          window.location.replace(loginUrl);
        }
      } else {
        next();
      }
    });

    export default router;
```

Comment: I am assuming you are using the @dsb-norge/vue-keycloak-js package, if so you need to register VueKeyCloak for use with your Vue app; see https://github.com/dsb-norge/vue-keycloak-js#usage

Comment: yes, and i can access $keycloak property in components but not in my ```router.beforeEach``` and i don't know why. But ```Vue.prototype.$keycloak``` work.

Comment: to get more help on this, can you please have a small reproducible version of your app somewhere online; I recommend using something like https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 0):

That's most likely due to the `$keycloak` attribute not being defined on the `Vue` class. You can hack around this by using `(router.app as any).$keycloak...`, however that's not type-safe and is generally not recommended. You could also register `$keycloak` as a Vue plugin - check out [this article](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) for more information on plugins.

Does `$keycloak` need to be defined on the Vue instance or is there another way that you could implement that?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I can access $keycloak in all components but i don't have access in my ```router.beforeeach``` i saw that Vue.prototype.$keycloak works also in my ```router.beforeeach```